# custom transition classes don't work on Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, css-transitions, tailwind-css, laravel-jetstream

I'm trying to use some transition in my code using Vue.js with Tailwinds. My environment include Laravel Jetstream with Inertia that comes with vue.

I notices that using this form everything work:

```html
<transition name="some-name">
  <div v-if="something"></div>
 </transition>
```

and this classes in my CSS:

```css
.some-name-enter {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.some-name-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.some-name-leave-active,
.some-name-enter-active {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

but when i try to use this sintax:

```html
<transition           
  enter-active-class="transition ease-out duration-100 transform"
  enter-from-class="opacity-0 scale-95"
  enter-to-class="opacity-100 scale-100"
  leave-active-class="transition ease-in duration-75 transform"
  leave-from-class="opacity-100 scale-100"
  leave-to-class="opacity-0 scale-95"
>
  <div v-if="something"></div>
</transition>
```

it is not working.. i just would like to use tailwind classes for the transition, they are very easy to use and there is no need to write lots of rows of css.

i dont know if it is important but i am using vue 2.6.12. thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beginning for both the *enter* and *leave* classes does not need the *from*. That is, they are just *enter-class*  and *leave-class* and not *enter-from-class* and *leave-from-class* as per [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Custom-Transition-Classes).

Answer (score 3):

For vue-2 users, you may follow what is mentioned in @ValheruBorn's answer.
For vue-3 users, this should work. Also, check the hooks [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/transitions-enterleave.html#custom-transition-classes)

This worked for me:

```
<transition
  enter-active-class="duration-300 ease-out"
  enter-from-class="transform opacity-0 scale-75"
  enter-to-class="opacity-100 scale-100"
  leave-active-class="duration-200 ease-in"
  leave-from-class="opacity-100 scale-100"
  leave-to-class="transform opacity-0 scale-75"
>
  <div v-if="something"></div>
</transition>
```

Even this works for me:

```
<transition name="fade">
  <div v-if="something"></div>
</transition>
```

add use this css

```
.fade-enter-active { @apply duration-300 ease-out }
.fade-enter-from { @apply transform opacity-0 scale-75 }
.fade-enter-to { @apply opacity-100 scale-100 }
.fade-leave-active { @apply transform duration-200 ease-in }
.fade-leave-from { @apply opacity-100 scale-100 }
.fade-leave-to { @apply opacity-0 scale-75 }
```