# Vue Transition with Tailwind

Tags: html, vuejs3, tailwind-css, transition, vite

Why do Tailwind do not work directly on element?

### This does not work:

```
<template>
      <transition
        enter-class="opacity-0"
        enter-active-class="transition-opacity duration-300 ease-out"
        leave-class="opacity-0"
        leave-active-class="transition-opacity duration-300 ease-out"
      >
        Test
      </transition>
</template>
```

### But this:

```
<template>
    <transition name="fade">
        Test
    </transition>
</template>
<style>
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  @apply transition-opacity duration-300 ease-out;
}
.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-active {
  @apply opacity-0;
}
</style>
```

I need to get it work like in "But this", because I use Nuxt with vite and I do not get scss to work, so @apply is not an option.

THanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Different Syntax between Vue2 and Vue3.
Thanks to this post [custom transition classes don't work on Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65893602/custom-transition-classes-dont-work-on-vue-js)

```
<transition
    enter-active-class="duration-300 ease-out"
    enter-from-class="transform opacity-0"
    enter-to-class="opacity-100"
    leave-active-class="duration-200 ease-in"
    leave-from-class="opacity-100"
    leave-to-class="transform opacity-0"
  >
        Test
</transition>
```

Answer (score 16):

Here are my `tailwind transition live templates` in `phpstorm`. Replace the `$SELECTION$` parameter with what you want to transition or use it as is:

#### FadeIn

```
<transition
  enter-from-class="opacity-0"
  enter-active-class="transition duration-300">
  $SELECTION$
</transition>
```

#### FadeOut

```
<transition
  leave-to-class="opacity-0"
  leave-active-class="transition duration-300">
  $SELECTION$
</transition>
```

#### Fade (if you need both)

```
<transition
  enter-from-class="opacity-0"
  leave-to-class="opacity-0"
  enter-active-class="transition duration-300"
  leave-active-class="transition duration-300">
  $SELECTION$
</transition>
```

#### SlideIn

```
<transition
  enter-from-class="translate-x-[150%] opacity-0"
  enter-active-class="transition duration-300">
  $SELECTION$
</transition>
```

#### SlideOut

```
<transition
  leave-to-class="translate-x-[150%] opacity-0"
  leave-active-class="transition duration-300">
  $SELECTION$
</transition>
```

#### Slide

```
<transition
  enter-from-class="translate-x-[150%] opacity-0"
  leave-to-class="translate-x-[150%] opacity-0"
  enter-active-class="transition duration-300"
  leave-active-class="transition duration-300">
  $SELECTION$
</transition>
```

Hope it helps.